# Rational function to find minimum surface area of cylinder

Tags: geometry, rational-functions

I have developed the formula to determine the radius of a cylinder with a fixed volume:

$$ f(x) = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{V}{\pi}}\ $$

Substituted into the formula for the surface area of a cylinder, I get the following function. This would give me the minimum surface area of a cylinder for a given volume.

$$
S(V) = 2\pi(\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{V}{\pi}})^2+2\pi(2 * \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{V}{\pi}})
$$

However, my assignment for class asks for a *rational* function for this problem. How could I take my existing function and make it rational?

Comment: What's the height of the cylinder? what is $x$? please explain yourself.

Comment: note that the units in your derivation are wrong: you can't add two numbers with different dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the cylinder in question has $h=r$, so that:
$$r=\sqrt[3]{V/\pi}$$
The surface area is then:
$$A=2\pi r^2 + 2\pi r h=4\pi r^2=4(\pi V)^{2/3}$$
This of course is not a rational function in $V$ (and never will be), but is a rational function in $r$. Perhaps this is what the assignment means?

Comment: I believe so. It just asks for the minimum surface area for a given volume.